# Use VS Online "Command Line" task with relative paths

Tags: build, nuget, azure-devops

I'm trying to use the new VS Online Build process and, specifically, package my app as a NuGet package.

To do so I have to execute something like "nuget pack". My source code is in GitHub and there, under the root folder, I have a folder called .nuget with all necessary to do the packaging.

I've added to my build template a "Command Line" step with this parameters:

- tool: C:\a\9ea8689c\myusername\myproject.nuget\nuget.exe
- arguments: pack

Everything else is defaults, included working folder. This works. However when I've tried to replace the absolute path for something like ".nuget/nuget.exe" or .nuget/nuget.exe or even changing the working folder to .nuget and from there just type "nuget.exe" it repeatedly fails because it can't find the tool.

Am I missing something? Should the task work with relative paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use absolute paths leveraging [TFS Environment Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx) like `TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY.`

In a batch file it is something like

```
echo Launching my own NuGet copy
%TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY%\myproject.nuget\nuget.exe
```

Comment: For a more specific description of VS Online vNext Build environment variables, check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/overview

Comment: On my vNext TFS 2015 build, i can only get value from the source dir variable, without the leading TF_  ... like this $(BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `$(BUILD.SOURCESDIRECTORY)\NuGet.exe`.
Notice the dot instead of underscore. I have put my NuGet.exe in the main repository folder, in my case NuGet 3.5 Beta.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vskd.png]